# Why is this extremely simple form not getting an upcast entity from its route?

Tags: 8, forms, routes

I have a `my_job_board.routing.yml`:

```
my_job_board.user_register_form:
  path: '/my-job-board/register/{user_role}'
  defaults:
    _form: '\Drupal\my_job_board\Form\UserRegisterForm'
    _title: 'Register for My Job Board'
  requirements:
    _access_user_register: 'TRUE'
```

(this is nearly identical to the route defined at line 56 of User module's [`user.routing.yml`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21user.routing.yml/8.4.x)),

and a `src/Form/UserRegisterForm.php`:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\my_job_board\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\user\RoleInterface;

class UserRegisterForm extends FormBase {

  public function getFormId() {
    return 'my_job_board_user_register';
  }

  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state, RoleInterface $user_role = NULL) {
    var_dump($user_role);
    return $form;
  }

  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  }

}
```

(my `buildForm()` has an identical signature to that of [`Drupal\user\Form\UserPermissionRoleSpecificForm`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21src%21Form%21UserPermissionsRoleSpecificForm.php/class/UserPermissionsRoleSpecificForm/8.4.x) which corresponds to the route I mentioned above).

Visiting `/my-job-board/register/employer` gives me the following error:

```
TypeError: Argument 3 passed to Drupal\my_job_board\Form\UserRegisterForm::buildForm() must be an instance of Drupal\user\RoleInterface, string given in Drupal\my_job_board\Form\UserRegisterForm->buildForm() (line 31 of modules/custom/my_job_board/src/Form/UserRegisterForm.php).
```

If i visit the same path with `string` instead of `RoleInterface` as the 3rd typehint for `buildForm()`, I see the output of `var_dump($user_role)`: `string(8) "employer"`.

Why am I not getting a `RoleInterface` passed into `buildForm()`? What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems entity routes (beginning `entity.`), like those in the user module, get the [`Drupal\Core\ParamConverter\EntityConverter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21ParamConverter%21EntityConverter.php/class/EntityConverter/8.4.x) converter automatically applied; other routes don't.

You should be able to apply it yourself easily enough:

```
my_job_board.user_register_form:
  path: '/my-job-board/register/{user_role}'
  defaults:
    _form: '\Drupal\my_job_board\Form\UserRegisterForm'
    _title: 'Register for My Job Board'
  requirements:
    _access_user_register: 'TRUE'
  options:
    parameters:
      user_role:
        type: entity:user_role
```

See [Parameter upcasting in routes](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/parameter-upcasting-in-routes) for more info.